# Why can I assign to a variable declared after the initalizer, but not print it?

Tags: java

I'm plaing with the initialization order and cannot explain why line 7 is compiled `b = 3;` but the next line 8 `System.out.println("b: " + b);` isn't. Can somebody explain this and fill up this knowledge gap?

Without line 8 the code compiles well and print "2 4".

```java
public class InitializationOrder {

    Integer a = 1;

    {
        a = 2;
        b = 3;
        System.out.println("b: " + b); // DOES NOT COMPILE
// InitializationOrder.java:8: error: illegal forward reference
//         System.out.println("b: " + b);
//                                    ^
// 1 error
// error: compilation failed
    }

    Integer b = 4;

    public InitializationOrder() {
        System.out.println(a + " " + b); // 2 4 - when line 8 is commented
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InitializationOrder obj = new InitializationOrder();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using `b` before declaring it which is why it doesn't compile when you print `b`. Line 8 compiles fine because you've declared both `a` and `b` before using them in `println()` statement.

Comment: but if comment the line 8 it this will compiled well, and there is also usage of b. (b = 3)

Comment: But you still can't "use" b. Try `a = b`. Doesn't work for the same reason. Not sure why the compiler lets you assign some value to `b`. But as soon as you try to access `b` it will blow up. And that's the most important part.

Comment: Then the rule: the variable can be assigned before declaration but cannot be "used".

Answer (score 4):

This is part of the restrictions on field references in initializers as documented by the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3):

> References to a field are sometimes restricted, even through the field is in scope. The following rules constrain forward references to a field (where the use textually precedes the field declaration) as well as self-reference (where the field is used in its own initializer).

> ...

> **For a reference by simple name to an instance variable f declared in class C, it is a compile-time error if:**
>
> - The reference appears either in an instance variable initializer of C or in an instance initializer of C (§8.6); and
> - The reference appears in the initializer of f's own declarator or at a point to the left of f's declarator; and
> - The reference is not on the left hand side of an assignment expression (§15.26); and
> - The innermost class enclosing the reference is C.

The JLS describes why these restrictions apply:

> The restrictions above are designed to catch, at compile time, circular or otherwise malformed initializations.

So basically to avoid scenarios like:

```
class Test {
    int i = j;
    int j = i;
}
```

(even though in your case printing the field may not be a dangerous thing to do)

Comment: Is there any use case for allowing assignment before declaration?

Comment: @kapex if the declaration contains an initializer then I don't see a use case for it.

Comment: Integer a = 1;
    {
        a = 2;
        b = 3;
    }
    Integer b;

this can be the use case. Output is: "2 3".

Comment: @jarek maybe an example, but not a real use case; why would I not just do `Integer a = 2; Integer b = 3;`? (unless I want to do code harder to read; or test developers knowledge)

Comment: Yes, I agree that it isn't real use case, only for fun.

Comment: "The reference is not on the left hand side of an assignment expression (§15.26);"

This is the answer to my question. Thanks.

"The reference appears either in an instance variable initializer of C or in an instance initializer of C (§8.6);"

but still into an instance initializer, hmm...

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse I get a better Error message:

```
Cannot reference a field before it is defined
```

Now it should be pretty obvious why you get the error.